# Stripe configuration endpoint Laravel cashier

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I have been some problems making webhooks of Stripe works with my application. 
So after being able to create, update, delete, resume subscriptions, and create my endpoint to my domain:

```
 www.domain.com
```

I always recieve 419 http code when a user interact with my application.

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 2):

I write this in case helps someone:

My problem was I hadn't included a route for stripe in my web.php, like this:

```
 Route::post(
   'stripe/webhook',
   '\Laravel\Cashier\Http\Controllers\WebhookController@handleWebhook'
);
```

and you can't forget to include stripe in your verifycsrftoken middleware, like this:

```
 protected $except = [
   'stripe/*',
 ];
```

and once you have done it, you have to configure your endpoint in stripe dashboard to call to the previous route:

```
 www.domain.com/stripe/webhook
```

and include all the events you want to listen to.

To test it in local you can use stripe cli, that works perfectly:
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli

Comment: The relevant docs for all this are at https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/billing#handling-stripe-webhooks. "Webhooks & CSRF Protection" and "Defining Webhook Event Handlers".